# multiple dropdowns caret up and down onclick - vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple dropdowns that I want when clicking on one dropdown its caret be up instead of down and all its dropdowns siblings caret be down

```
<div>
<div><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down toggle"></i></div>
<div><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down toggle"></i></div>
<div><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down toggle"></i></div>
<div><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down toggle"></i></div>
</div>
```

this is my code

```
//tabs arrows up-down classes
let toggleButton = document.querySelector('.small-tab-container');
let toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');

function toggleCaret() {
  toggle.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
  toggle.classList.toggle('fa-caret-up');
}
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleCaret, false);
```

of course **this code working only on first caret** because I didn't loop throw siblings. I need to know:

1- how to loop on them?

2- how to make one of the carets are up all other
carets are down?

I need to achieve this **using pure javascript**

Comment: You'll need to select all the elements by using the ```document.querySelectorAll()```. Which will return a nodelist. You can use a normal for loop to loop through it like with normal arrays in js. And I'm not sure what you mean by 'how to make one of the carets are up all other carets are down?`. But you can make 1 dropdown unique by giving it an id. So only 1 will stay down and the others go up.

Comment: I need to use query select all to the button and the caret, how to apply onclick with query select all